# Using Vector Curves Nodes for transitions

Tags: materials, node-editor

I am trying to use a Vector Curves node to describe a abrupt transition based on a value. In the following figure, I have setup a test case where I am trying to make the material transition from blue to red at .8 to .81 . However the transition happens at .62 to .63 (see Combine XYZ). It appears that the mapping is aprox .2 ahead of its expected value (see the Greater Than node). Does anyone have any advice on what I am doing wrong?

Note material is just an example to illustrate a more general problem I am having. I realize there are other methods of building the transition, but I like the idea of using a curve to describe the mapping. 
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To achieve an abrubt transition, you only need the *Greater Then* Node.

[image: a]

[image]

It seems that *Vector Curves* Node had some problem with too close points.
Everything works well when points are more distant.
[image]
[image]
[image]